# Text not wrapping inside div on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a block of text inside a div tag that looks great on the desktop, but when you shrink the page for mobile and the div's get stacked, the text does not wrap and just trails off the side. I am not very experienced with this, but I'd really like to learn how to fix this.

My CSS for the div

```
#homemain {
line-height: 15px;
background-color: transparent;
height: 500px;
width: 600px;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 10px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

My HTML on the page

```
<div id="homemain">
[rev_slider home_small]
&nbsp;
<h2>[title size="2"]Explore Our Services[/title]</h2>
Text text text, texty text, lots and lots of stuff about our services and what we do. We really want you to use our services and what not. We're the best.
</div>
```

This is a page inside WordPress btw, if that makes much difference here. I did not create the page, just inherited it and tasked with fixing it because I'm the most "techie" person in the office. Lucky me! Any help on this would be helpful.

Comment: If this is the code for mobile as well, the width is 600px so the text will span across that.  Add a media query targeting the screen width you want to support and set a smaller width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you want a responsive layout, yet you're using a non-responsive approach. Remember that in order to get a responsive layout, you need to think it in terms of non-fixed sizes (%, rem, etc)

So, in your code, where you have this:

```
#homemain {
line-height: 15px;
background-color: transparent;
height: 500px;
width: 600px;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 10px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

You should change it to :

```
#homemain {
line-height: 15px;
background-color: transparent;
height: 500px;
max-width: 100%;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 10px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

However, if you need to have that 600px width on desktop, then you can use this:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    #homemain {
    line-height: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 500px;
    width:600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    }
}
```

and for smaller screens:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #homemain {
    line-height: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 500px;
    width:600px;
    max-width: 320px; /* or whatever size you want */
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    }
}
```

This way, by using [media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html), you can have more control over your layout on different sizes

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't realize that you can change each div for the media type. I've updated that and it looks great on everything I've tested!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing (I suspect) is that `#homemain` is still displaying as `600px` wide, even on screens which have a screen-width smaller than `600px`.

What you need is for `#homemain` to be full-screen-width on screens narrower than `600px` but no more than `600px` wide on screens wider than `600px`.

Try something like:

```
#homemain {
[...]
width: 99%;
max-width: 600px;
[...]
}
```